# Convert assac to string in PHP

Tags: php, json, string, converters, associative-array

I'm trying to convert JSON-Object like `[{"text":"hallo"},{"text":"hello"}]`  into a string which should look like "hallo hello".

At the moment, I'm decoding the JSON-Object with `json_decode($words, true);`

The result is being sent to a function than, which looks like:

```
function assocToString($assoc)
{
    $ergString="";

    foreach($assoc as $key => $value)
    {
        if($ergString=="")
        {
            $ergString = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $ergString .= $value;
        }

        $ergString .= " ";
    }

    return $ergString;
}
```

I get errors like "Array to string conversion" all the time, maybe someone of you could please as be as kind as to help me out?

Comment: `var_dump($assoc);` shows what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This apparently mean that your array was an multi-dimension array. Try to put another foreach loop inside the existing one.

Use vardump or print_r to check how does the current data store in $assoc look like

```
foreach($assoc as $key)
{
   foreach($key as $value){
    if($ergString=="")
    {
        $ergString = $value;
    }
    else
    {
        $ergString .= $value;
    }

    $ergString .= " ";
   }
}
```

Try this see wether working